# Array.find function in REACT JS Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am new to REACT and trying to use array.find function. Getting error Cannot read property `first_name` of undefined.
When I declare JSON array inside `RenderIt` function. Not sure, why `REACT` cannot see results array.

```
export default function App() {

  const [results, SetResults] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    const JSON = [{
        EMPLID: '345386',
        first_name: 'David',
      },
      {
        EMPLID: '345397',
        first_name: 'Luca',
      },
    ]
    SetfName(JSON[0].first_name)
    SetResults(JSON)
  }, [])

  const RenderIt = () => {
    let found = results.find(element => element.EMPLID === '345397')
    return ( < div > {
        found.first_name
      } < /div>)
    }

    return ( <
      div className = "App" >
      <
      h1 > First Name < /h1> <
      h2 > {
        (RenderIt())
      } < /h2>       <
      /div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is SetfName a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function provided to `useEffect` only runs **after** the first render, so during that first render, `results` is `[]`, so the `find` can't find anything and returns `undefined`, which in turn means that `found` is `undefined`, and thus doesn't have the `first_name` property, which is the error you're seeing.

You want to check whether `results` has anything, and the only optionally render the `RenderIt` stuff if so.

Put this at the bottom inside your `h2`:

```
{ results !== [] && RenderIt() }
```

Or you can change RenderIt to:

```
const RenderIt = () => {
    let found = results.find(element => element.EMPLID === '345397')
    if (!found) return '';
    return (<div> {found.first_name} </div>)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luke.
I tried this and getting same error message.
{ results !== [] && RenderIt() }
Still not clear, the order of execution.
If I use results.map inside RenderIt(), it works fine. However, if I use results.find it does not.

Comment: try the second solution

Comment: Luke Storry, the second solution worked. Thanks for taking time and responding.
So, is this right order of execution?

1. First render (results is set to [])
2. useEffect (results is set to [JSON]) 
3. Second render (RenderIt() call gets first_name)

Comment: Yeah! You can render "Loading..." or something in that first render too, whilst the json is being set

Comment: Thanks. Closing this request. Appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know but i think maybe setFName is the undefined?

```
const [fName, setFName] = useState("")
```

Comment: Please ignore this statement SetfName(JSON[0].first_name). I am sure its not causing issue.